Chat search does not bring up new results
Searching in chat returns results but the newest ones it brings back stop somewhere between 2024-06-14 03:00 UTC and 2024-06-14 04:00 UTC. I did not find the exact point but it should be in this region.
Messages from before 03:00 UTC show up. New ones do not.
Example: searching for "moved to Chimney" in the Tavern on the Meta returns this message from  2024-06-14 02:18 as the newest. No messages after it are returned.
This one from 2024-06-14 12:02 also contains the same phrase "moved to Chimney" and is not returned in the search result.
Searching for "missing because of a bug is a different issue" does not find the message from 2024-06-14 07:33. Any message after it does not show in search results.
This seems to affect https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ and https://chat.stackoverflow.com but not https://chat.stackexchange.com/

Yup, reproduced. Possible related bug.
